# Calculating percentage value from other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate a value "ordered gross max". The variation in min max depends on ordered quantity. We have value ordered, ordered_min, ordered_max and ordered_gross. Ordered_min and Ordered_max can be 3, 5 , 10 or 15 % of the ordered amount (depending upon the ordered quantity). Same goes for ordered_gross. I want to calculate ordered_gross_max. And what i am doing currently is first calculating the percentage and then calculating "ordered gross max" manually. Not sure if this is the right approach. Can someone please guide if there could be another way of achieving this,

```
SELECT ordered, ordered_min, ordered_max,ordered_gross ,
ordered_gross+(ordered_gross*((ordered - ordered_min)/ordered)) "ordered gross max"
FROM ORDERTABLE WHERE ORDER_NO = '1051'
```

Comment: Can you please share the current output and your expected output?

Comment: @jishansiddique i am already getting my desired output, just wanted to know if this approach ok calculating "ordered gross max" is ok or not

Comment: So it's ok just check `NULL` any columns values

Comment: If you are using Oracle 12c or higher then you can use generated column.